# пагинация на php + mysql + js

Tags: php, javascript

здравствуйте, сделал пагинацию и она работает но есть один нюанс. Я вывожу количество ссылок по страницам на php то есть от 1.....25 и при клике на эту ссылку я не передаю get параметр а обновляю контент через ajax, и я не знаю как мне скрыть часть ссылок пагинации, если у меня много контента то пагинация идет в 3 ряда, как посоветуете исправить это что бы видимых ссылок было штук 10

Comment: Может пример кода js и php приведете?

Comment: вывод пагинации перенес на js вот код:
`    $('#root').prepend(
        `<ul style="float: right" class="pagination">
        <li class="link_pagination prev_link"><a href="#!"><i class=" material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
               
        <li class="link_pagination next_link waves-effect"><a href="#!"><i class=" material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
        </ul>`
    );
    for (var i = count_page - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        $('.prev_link').after('<li class=" l_p link_pagination" data-link="' + i + '"><a href="">' + parseInt(i+1) + '</a></li>' );
    }`

Comment: хм может просто попробовать скрывать ссылки js или css? или надо придумать разбивание на массиви ссылок?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю логику ваших действий, зачем каждый раз перерисовывать пагинатор полностью, но если уж хочется просто удаляйте старый, **$('.pagination').remove();**, а потом уже выполняйте то что вы написали